# Why does WiX ignore a custom function?

Tags: c, wix, custom-function

I have created a sample WiX project to test C-based custom actions. Here is the C code of the custom action function DLL:

```
unsigned WINAPI SetDeviceType (MSIHANDLE installer) {
    MsiSetProperty(installer, TEXT("DEVICETYPE"), TEXT("3"));
    return(ERROR_SUCCESS);
}
```

and here are the  important parts of my WiX project:

```
<Binary Id="Message" SourceFile="Message.dll" />
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="MyCompany">
            <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Test">
                <Component Id="TestFolder" Guid="c54ec545-4074-424f-a54e-b57f375ed3fc">
                    <File Id="Setup_wixproj" Source="setup.wixproj" Vital="yes" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="TestFolder1" Guid="c54ec5f5-4074-424f-a54e-b57f375ed3fc">
                    <File Id="Setup1_wixproj" Source="setup1.wixproj" Vital="yes" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
<Feature Id="AllFeature" Title="All" Level="1">
    <Feature Id="TempFeature" Title="Temp" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="TestFolder" />
        <Condition Level="0">
            <![CDATA[DEVICETYPE <> 3]]>
        </Condition>
    </Feature>
    <Feature Id="AlwaysFeature" Title="Always" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="TestFolder1" />
    </Feature>
</Feature>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="Launch" After="AppSearch" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<CustomAction Id="Launch" BinaryKey="Message" DllEntry="SetDeviceType" Return="check" Execute="immediate" HideTarget="no" />
```

Meaningful excerpts of the MSI log are given below.
[...]

```
Action start 10:21:42: Launch.
MSI (s) (E4:48) [10:21:42:319]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIE532.tmp, Entrypoint: SetDeviceType
MSI (s) (E4:E4) [10:21:42:320]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (E4:E4) [10:21:42:321]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 3000 (0xBB8).
MSI (s) (E4:54) [10:21:42:344]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (E4:54) [10:21:42:345]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
MSI (s) (E4!44) [10:21:42:357]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DEVICETYPE property. Its value is '3'.
Action ended 10:21:42: Launch. Return value 1.
```

[...]

```
Action start 10:21:42: InstallValidate.
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:361]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its current value is 'ec922ccc9406da4baac466ba2db559b9'.
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:361]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Dialog 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:361]: Feature: TempFeature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:361]: Feature: AllFeature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:361]: Feature: AlwaysFeature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:361]: Component: TestFolder; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:361]: Component: TestFolder1; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:361]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Registry 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:361]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: BindImage 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:362]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ProgId 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:362]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PublishComponent 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:362]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: SelfReg 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:362]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Extension 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:362]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Font 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:362]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Shortcut 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:362]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Class 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:362]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Icon 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:362]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: TypeLib 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:365]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: _RemoveFilePath 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying CostingComplete property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '1'.
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Registry 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: BindImage 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ProgId 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PublishComponent 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: SelfReg 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Extension 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Font 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Shortcut 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Class 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Icon 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:366]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: TypeLib 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:367]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:367]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: FilesInUse 
MSI (s) (E4:8C) [10:21:42:371]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
Action ended 10:21:42: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
```

[...]

```
Action start 10:20:59: ExecuteAction.
```

[...]

According to the MSI log The custom action function is called and the property is set. But the condition in the `feature` is never met and the file is not installed. If I remove the condition, both files are installed.
Why does it behave like this?

Comment: I would suggest simplifying your assumptions, and thus the question. Instead of invoking a DLL, just use a type 51 SetProperty CA. And compare against just setting the property in the package itself, or from the command line. (I believe there's an ordering issue possible with feature conditions, but I thought it had to do with its schedule relative to file costing.)

Comment: @Michael Urman It is a training project. In a real project I would handle several values of a property. So I would like to find out what I am doing wrong in these circumstances.

Comment: Assuming you mean your CA would set the property to one of several different values, that's all well and good, but it doesn't seem like your question is really about the CA. So, again, start by testing when you can get the effect you want based on the value of the property. Timing in the sequence can be very important.

Comment: according to the MSI log (see updated question) the property is set before any activity with any feature. The property is set at 10:21:42:357, the features are first used at 10:21:42:361 and the installation of the features starts at 10:20:59. Any further ideas, please?

Comment: Is the behavior different if you run it as `msiexec /i your.msi DEVICETYPE=3`? If so, you have an ordering issue. If not, you have a problem with how you condition against the property.